# Stuck on why my program wont work...?

Tags: android

Ive been trying to make an app for my girlfriend and I which will allow us to type messages and then allow th other to read it and click the button below to give a response and keep this going back and forth. I've gotten somewhat far I guess but I'm completely stuck on why it wont work now. Ive been working based on the skeleton of this [code](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Originally, the code allowed me to open the application and then once I pressed the button at the bottom, it would give me an error saying that the program is no longer able to run and that I had to "force close" it. I fixed that but then when I did, the MainActivity window would keep reappearing when I would click the button. I attempted to fix that but now the application doesn't open anymore

I tried the debugger but I'm not advanced enough to figure out what it really says....

If you would like project folder or somehow upload here, I have no problem doing that. Just trying to make this as a little present for my girl. Thanks in advance!

[edit]
I should mention that there are no syntax errors

[edit]
Manifest code

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.chatfriends"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="OldTargetApi">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity__alex" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[edit]
MainActivity:

```
package com.chatfriends;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

     public void startActivity_alex(View v){
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity__alex.class);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
 }
```

**Edit:** Now the app runs, but when I click on the button below it gives me an error.

[Here is the catlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCO5o.jpg)

Comment: If you want help, you need to post the code that you have tried where the problem is coming from and the logcat in code blocks instead of using a link. With that being said, it looks like you may not have your activity declared in the manifest

Comment: I believe you have changed the name of your class to something other then MainActivity?

Comment: Edit your question, paste your code and stacktrace here itself..

Comment: the stack trace says it cant find the "com.chatfriends.chatfriends.MainActivity". Are you sure the package name is correct??

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
   <activity
        android:name=".chatfriends.MainActivity"
```

to

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
```

inside your `manifest` because you MainActivity is inside `com.chatfriends` package and not in `com.chatfriends.chatfriends`

Answer (score 0):

You should define your activity name in the `Manifest` file as:

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

instead of `android:name=".chatfriends.MainActivity"`

Because the error stating the class *`com.chatfriends.chatfriends.MainActivity`* is not found, and you have your `MainActivity` class directly under *`com.chatfrieds`* package.

**Edit**

The error message tells you **"NoSuchMethodException"** `onClick(View)`. It seems you defined `onClick` handler or your button in the `layout` XML file.

You need to add this function in your activity:

```
public void onClick(View view){

  // Add your code here for button click

}
```

Comment: in the MainActivity file, would i add it like this? Thank you so much for helping this much === public void onClick(View view){
  startActivity_alex(view);
 }

Comment: Yes it should work, or simply rename your method startActivity_alex(View view) to onClick(View view)